# How to query the github file size in Google BigQuery?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I need to get the size statistics for the files in the github open source repository.
For example, the number of files less than 1M is XXX or 70% of the total files.

I found that the files in [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents] are all less than 1M(though I don't know why). So I decided to choose [githubarchive:month.202005] or other month.

But I didn't find the **"file size"** field in [githubarchive:month.202005].So I would like to ask how to query the size of the file in [githubarchive:month.202005]? Then I can use the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58487874/group-by-range-of-values-in-bigquery) to get the results by size??

I am new to bigquery, and the question may be silly. But I really need a solution. Or have statistics or literature that I can cite, which has the size statistics for files on github. [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents] does not mention why only files less than 1M were selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a wrong interpretation, since `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.content` public table holds text file data in `content` column for items under 1 MiB on the HEAD branch, for others you'll discover just `null` values:

```
SELECT id,size,content  FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents` where size > 1048576 LIMIT 100
```

Therefore, you are not limited analyzing files inventory in this case if I properly understand your point.

Comment: Thank you very much! My understanding is that only files less than 1MB are saved their "content" in  [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.contents] . Although other files' "content" are "null" value , they still have information such as "id" and "size" in the table. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you're still able to fetch `id` and `size` columns for files > 1MB. If you decide my answer helped you with the research, then consider [accept/up vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) action in order to finalize the question and support other contributors.